# Does each new incarnation of the Doctor retain all the skills displayed by previous incarnations?

Tags: doctor-who

I remember the second Doctor (Troughton) was often warbling away on his flute and the third Doctor (Pertwee) was a master of Venusian Aikido.

So do all the subsequent Doctors also have those abilities?

I realise they have different personalities but their long-learned knowledge is passed on, so are their minor skills passed on as well?

Comment: Nice. I made an additional edit, mainly to make the title a bit more specific to what I think you're asking here. Go ahead and reverse the edit if you disapprove (I won't take offense).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Certain skills (like Venusian aikido) are used by multiple incarnations (https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Venusian_aikido), suggesting that the skills transfer, but interests don't - so for example, the Fourth Doctor could play the recorder, if he choose to, but doesn't choose to, due to personality changes.

It's possible that some skills atrophy with time independent of regeneration, just as anyone might forget a language they knew as a child.